# Calculating per cent improvement in test error

Tags: machine-learning, percentage

I’ve come across this statement regarding an improvement percentage and I don’t know if it’s okay. It says this:

> The training error and test error using the neighborhood model are
>   0.34 and 0.54 respectively, compared to 0.51 and 0.64 using the baseline predictor. This represents a 16% improvement in RMSE for the
>   test set.

How does it get that 16%?

I would do:

Initial : 0.64
Final :0. 54

final - initial = |0.54 - 0.64 |=0.10

0.10 / 0.64 = 0.1562

0.1562 x100 = 15.72%

Is that correct?

[image]

Comment: You are comparing 0.54 (test error with your model) to 0.64 (test error with the baseline predictor), so your result is how much much the model improved the results in the test set.

Comment: I get that! It was confusing of how it calculated that 16%. I wanted to be sure I was doing the right calculation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your calculation is correct. I've removed my previous answer because it was based on a misinterpretation.

Comment: Actually, the baseline model (predictor) performs worse

Comment: @Delan My mistake, I misinterpreted your question initially.